# What exactly does it mean to say that a (real) function is defined on an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have been considering the following theorem:

> Let $I$ be an interval and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Then, if $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x \in I$, then the function is strictly increasing on the interval $I$.

However, my notes then go on to say that the above "only applies to functions defined on an interval" and that the function $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ may have a positive derivative everywhere, but fail to be increasing. Take, as an example of this, the function $g : \mathbb{R} \backslash \{ 0 \}$ with $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$.

What does it mean to say that the domain of a function is an interval? Surely we can define the aforementioned function on the interval $[-1,1]$, but it would still not comply with the theorem?

Comment: You can't extend that $f$ to $0$ in a way that makes it differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the hypotheses of the theorem you mentioned is that $f : I \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable on the interval $I$.

Differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point.  Therefore, without continuity at a point there cannot be differentiability at that point.

As [Chappers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221811/chappers) mentioned in a comment, there's no way to extend $f(x) = -1/x$ to $[-1,1]$ so that $f(x)$ differentiable at $x=0$.  This is because there's no way to extend $f(x) = -1/x$ to even be *continuous* at $x=0$.  And this in turn is because there is a vertical asymptote at $x=0$.

So yes, you can define $f(x) = [-1,1]$ by giving it a value at $x=0$.  And it would comply with the theorem in the sense that it doesn't satisfy the hypotheses anymore, therefore the theorem doesn't even apply.

You asked a couple times what it means for the domain of a function to be an interval.  Is that really the question you wanted to ask?  My response would begin by defining what a domain is and what an interval is but based on the nature of your question I feel like you already know those things.  Roughly speaking, the domain of a function $f$ is the set of all numbers we're allowed to use as input to $f$.  An interval is a connected subset of the real line, i.e., a subset of the real numbers with no "holes" in it.  For example, $[-1,1]$ and $(12,+\infty)$ are both intervals.  But $[1,2) \cup (2,3]$ is not an interval because there's a hole at $2$.  But it is a union of two intervals.